# What does YouTube API V3 I.1 policy restriction mean?

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

YouTube API v3 has reduced our key from 640,000 queries per day to 0 (!!! and actually blocked us). This happened after submitting a request to enlarge our quota. They did this without any warning. We received an email 2 days later saying we are are out of compliance with
Policy I.1 (Additional Prohibitions): https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#i-additional-prohibitions

Our system allow users to organize and view YouTube videos in order to plan their event timeline, rather than copying the URL on a google doc the old way. Thus driving quality traffic to YouTube and providing value to YouTube users who can be monetized. 
We are a harmless small startup that has been using YouTube API for the past 4 years. After using the API in our product for that long, and finally growing our user base, we requested a higher quota and were revoked completely without any notice. 
We need help shedding light on what exactly YouTube Developer team think we are doing wrong that doesn't comply. 
The reason was complying with policy I.1. Can anyone give examples of things that they did that have been revoked due to policy I.1 so we can understand why YouTube thinks we are not in compliance? How do we get more specific details so we can fix this? how can we fix something so vague?

Example of our API call (NODE.js):

```
const response = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
            params: {
                key: OUR_BLOCKED_KEY,
                maxResults: 5,
                q: searchStr,
                part: 'snippet',
                type: 'video',
                fields: 'items(id/videoId,snippet(channelTitle,thumbnails/default/url,thumbnails/medium/url,title))'
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm having similar problems and it has proved absolutely impossible to get in touch with anyone who knows anything about this, whether via online chats, the official community forum, or a stackoverflow post. Both of which I was advised to try by someone from Google on the phone. Speaking of which, I tried calling tech support, customer support, sales, everything I could find both on the YouTube side and the Google side. My next attempt will be sending a physical letter to the postal address listed in the last email I got from them, Google LLC d/b/a YouTube, 901 Cherry Ave, San Bruno, CA 94066

Comment: You are not alone, but don't expect any help from YouTube of Google, or at least that is my experience (trying not to get sued here). I'm hoping others can also jump in here with any other information on the subject until we can resolve this kind of issue reliably. Actually, this begs the question: did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: no, it wasn't resolved, even after we met with a manager that we managed to get a hold of in YouTube and after a promise of him to take a look at it which they never did.
I recommend any business that thinks about using their API to understand that one day they can block you and and there's not a lot you can do about it.
Side note: other Google API that are paid are totally fine to use and in large volumes you just pay, which isn't the case with YouTube API